# how to append data after clear ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I need to append data after cleared in CKeditor but what happens is the all data cleared and no data appended

```
     $('.my_r_warning').on('click', function () {
                CKEDITOR.instances['js-ckeditor'].setData('');
            CKEDITOR.instances['js-ckeditor'].insertText('Reply :');
                $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $('#form').offset().top
                                    }, 2000)
          })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need insert data to clear ckeditor, you can just do like this

```
   $('.my_r_warning').on('click', function () {
                CKEDITOR.instances['js-ckeditor'].setData('Reply :');
                $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $('#form').offset().top
                                    }, 2000)
          })
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to append data once. If someone clicked more than once it append 'Reply ' more so I need to clear before append. Any suggestions

Comment: `setData()` doesn't append. It clears the data and inserts the new text.

Answer (score 0):

To insert data you can use [`editor.insertHtml()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) or [`editor.insertText()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertText). 
Please be aware that insertion happen in **current selection** inside editor. So if  you wish to append data (insert at the end), first you need to move/make selection in place where insertion needs to happen. You can manipulate with selection using [`CKEDITOR.dom.range`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) and [`CKEDITOR.dom.selection`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection)